# How to plot 3-d surface plot for varying values of Z?

Tags: python

I search a lot for the 3d surface plotting using mesh-grid but still unable to fix my issue.
Most of the examples use some equation for the z-component for each mesh-grid, like as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

def P(X, Y):
    return mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)      

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
jet = plt.get_cmap('jet')

x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 60)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 60)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = P(X, Y)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, cmap = jet, linewidth = 0)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, Z.max())

plt.show()
```

However, in my case data already include x, y, z in equal dimensions.
However, to create a mesh grid I need two-dimensional Z-parameter which I am not sure how can I get.

Below is an example dataset and the expect output plot.

May someone suggest how I can fix this.

```
#random 3d-dataset
s = np.random.uniform(-1,1,100)
t = np.random.uniform(-1,1,100)
z= np.random.uniform(100,500,100)
#meshgriding
x = np.linspace(-1,1,21)
y =  np.linspace(-1,1,21)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

My attempt:

Here is the expected output:

[image]

Comment: some clarifications are required: what are `s` and `t` in your code? How do you expect your `z` which consists of a random 1D array of length 100 to give you a surface plot like the one shown, especially given that your `x` and `y` axes are each of length 21? in order to plot a surface, you need `X`, `Y` and `Z` to be 2D arrays of a similar size.

Comment: @Hoodlum, s, t, z are my observational data points which is want to plot in a mesh grid of x, y. and then take the average values of z within each grid cell to plot a surface. If any grid cell is empty, we just mask that.

Comment: ok. what exactly do you mean by "mask" for an empty grid cell? do you want the cell to be empty?

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways you could approach this that I can think of.

1. Since your data is not evenly placed on a grid, the simplest way to display it is with a **scatter plot**. However, this clearly won't be a surface...
2. Alternatively, you can try and create a **triangle-based surface** from the raw data points. If your data is not too noisy and if it is relatively evenly distributed, this should give some pretty decent results.
3. If you really want a continuous, uniformly smooth surface, you will probably need to **interpolate** it from the data. Note: interpolation can be dangerous if there is a lot of noise in your data, and can lead to "overfitting" and curve explosions.
4. If your data is super noisy, you'll need to do some processing on it before you can properly display it. This might involve binning or averaging, but in any case, you'll probably need to implement this yourself, since the exact approach depends on your data.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def make_z_observable(s: np.ndarray, t: np.ndarray):
    '''create an obervable z which is not totally random, so we can have a decent plot'''
    if s.size != t.size:
        raise ValueError(f"{s.size=} does not match {t.size=}")
    z = 10*s**2 + 10*t**3 + np.random.uniform(-.1, .1, s.size)
    return z


# random 3d-dataset
s = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 100)
t = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, s.shape)
z = make_z_observable(s, t)


# option 1 : scatter plot the raw data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax = fig.add_axes(ax)
scatter = ax.scatter(s, t, z)

# option 2 : plot a surface from the raw data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax = fig.add_axes(ax)
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(s, t, z)

# option 3 : interpolate a continuous surface from the raw data
#   This requires messing around with the array shapes quite a
#   bit, sadly.
interpolator = LinearNDInterpolator(np.vstack((s, t)).T, z)
# create a regular grid of coordinates
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# for each coordinate, evaluate the interpolated z value. reshape the output to the correct size
Z = interpolator(np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())).T).reshape(X.shape)
# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax = fig.add_axes(ax)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

# show
plt.show()
```

Figure 1 : scatter plot
[image: scatter plot]

Figure 2 : tri-mesh surface plot
[image: trisurface plot]

Figure 3 : regular grid surface plot
[image: grid surface plot]

Comment: thanks for the reply. Indeed, it is very helpful for me. Case 3rd works in my case. But the problem is still there, in the example you care a z variable with a dimension much greater than s, t. Whereas, in my case, the dimension of s, t and z is same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? In the example `z` has the same shape/dimensions as `s` and `t`. This is specifically guaranteed in the `make_z_observable` function. Try adding `print(f'{s.shape=}, {t.shape=}, {z.shape=})` after the creation of the `z` variable to see this.